# writing a junit test case for the calling of a method

Tags: java, junit

i am using eclemma and trying to increase my test coverage:

so far this is my code:

```
 public RolesResponse findRolesByTenant(RolesRequest rolesRequest)
    {
        RolesResponse rolesResponse = new RolesResponse();
        List<Role> roleList = null;
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(rolesRequest.getTenantCode()))
        {
            roleList = roleFunctionService.getAllRolesAndFunctionsByTenant(rolesRequest.getTenantCode());

        }
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(roleList))
        {

            rolesResponse.setRoles(roleList);
        }
        else
        {

            rolesResponse.setError(LayerContextHolder.getErrorObject());
        }

        return rolesResponse;
    }
```

and here is my test:

```
@Test
    public void findRolesByTenantTest()
    {
        RolesRequest rolesRequest = new RolesRequest();
        rolesRequest.setTenantCode("test");
        ErrorObject errorObject = new ErrorObject();


        RolesResponse rolesResponse = rolesProcessService.findRolesByTenant(rolesRequest);
        Assert.assertNull(rolesResponse.getError());

    }
```

the only line eclemma is highlighting in red is this one:

```
rolesResponse.setError(LayerContextHolder.getErrorObject());
```

can someone help me in constructing the final test needed to cover this line

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not a fan of your test anyway - what are you trying to prove by the error being null?  That the list came back with something?  Also, are you certain that your service will return the result you want in your test every single time?

Don't think of tests in terms of coverage; this will lead to brittle tests and tests that give a false sense of security.  What you want to do is write tests that cover each condition that the code could encounter, and the line coverage can follow from that.

From your code, I see two cases.

- `roleFunctionService#getAllRolesByFunctionAndTenant` can return a non-empty list.

  - It's implied that the resultant `rolesResponse#roles` contains whatever was in the list provided by the method, and this should be verified.
  - It's also implied that there is no error set on the object, so it should be `null`.
- `roleFunctionService#getAllRolesByFunctionAndTenant` can return an empty list

  - Either the resultant `rolesResponse#roles` are empty or `null`; it'd be better if it were empty.
  - It's implied that there *is* an error on the object, which is specifically provided by `LayerContextHolder.getErrorObject()`.  You should check to see that it's exactly that.

You'll get to the whole approach of writing this test through the use of a [mocking framework](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: Couple of suggestions in addition to these good comments by @Makoto. 1) See if you can write tests before the code under test--it should help you with your design. 2) I like for my test method names to explain what is tested and since it's documentation, I abandon Java naming convention here. For example, "should_cope_with_empty_role_list" might be one case. 3) I don't care for that return type, RolesResponse. It feels like it's there so you can accommodate either success or failure, with different fields populated in each case. Simplify!

Comment: @Makoto, so regarding bullet point 5. i need to do an assertNotNull or assertNull on this. so apologies for code in comments but Assert.assertNull(roleFunctionService.getAllRolesAndFunctionsByTenant(rolesRequest.getTenantCode())??

how can you check for an error? is there something like assertError?

Comment: You would be extracting the context from the `rolesResponse` object, using its getters to do assertions against.  You would wind up using `assertTrue` to assert against fields on that object.